# How to access List inside Map in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, dictionary, thymeleaf

Consider the following map,

```
Map<String, List<String>> map=new HashMap<>();
```

I would like to put values into this map using thymeleaf. Now, how to insert list items into the map in thymeleaf.

For, `Map<String,String>` we would write something like `map['key']=val;`
How to do it for lists?
One way, I thought was keeping the `List<String>` in a class. For example,

```
class ListWrapper
{
public List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();

// setter and getter methods
}
```

and then write the map as

```
Map<String, ListWrapper> map=new HashMap<>();
```

and insert like this..

```
map['key'].list[0]='item 1';
map['key'].list[1]='item 2';
```

Is there any direct way, instead of writing a class unnecessarily?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think, you can simply call the method `List.add`: `map['key'].add('item1')`.

Comment: Why not use Guava's ListMultiMap instead of trying to roll your own?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write a class - you can use Guava's [ListMulitMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html).  Check out these [examples](http://java.dzone.com/articles/multimaps-google-guava).